# Python. Argparser. Removing not-needed arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I am parsing some command-line arguments, and most of them need to be passed to a method, but not all.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-d", "--dir", help = "Directory name", type = str, default = "backups")
parser.add_argument("-n", "--dbname", help = "Name of the database", type = str, default = "dmitrii")
parser.add_argument("-p", "--password", help = "Database password", type = str, default = "1123581321")
parser.add_argument("-u", "--user", help = "Database username", type = str, default = "Dmitriy")
parser.add_argument("-a", "--archive", help = "Archive backup", action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()

backup(**vars(args)) # the method where i need to pass most of the arguments, except archive. Now it passes all.
```

Comment: Either copy args and delete archive from it, or copy everything except archive.

Comment: I am very new to python, could you please help me. My list comprehension skill are at 0.

Comment: If `backup` is your own function, you can add `**kwargs` to its argument list.  Then it will accept the full `var(args)` without complaining.

Comment: @hpaulj Oh, thanks! That's even better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either create a new dictionary that does not have that key:

```
new_args = dict(k, v for k, v in args.items() if k != 'archive')
```

Or remove the key from your original dictionary:

```
archive_arg = args['archive'] # save for later
del args['archive'] #remove it
```

Comment: So, args is a dictionary of tuples? How do I delete an element from dictionary based only on one value of a tuple?

Comment: Thanks so much, that's what I needed but wasn't sure how to do.

Comment: @Anarion: `args.items()` returns a list of key-value pairs.  `if k != 'archive'` keeps items where the key is not `'archive'`.  `dict` builds a new dictionary out of the resulting tuples (`k, v`).  Removing a key is more straightforward: `del args[key]` removes the key from the dictionary.  If this answer is helpful, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: `args` from `parse_args` is not a dictionary.  It is a simple `argparser.Namespace` object.  `vars(args)` is a dictionary (with methods like `.items()`.

Comment: Your first code fragment has a syntax error: You need to parenthesise the `k, v` pair: `dict((k, v) for k, v in ...)`. Otherwise it looks like `k` is the first argument to `dict()`, followed by a generator expression (which is not allowed).