# 'for loop' for updating argparser argument

Tags: python, youtube-api, argparse

My code searches youtube video link for every line in file using 'for loop', and youtube api.

File line looks like this 'video_id name'. I am passing this video_id value to my function with 'argparser function' that fails. **After first iteration code fails** when trying to launch this `args = argparser.parse_args()`

Is there a way to maybe clear argparser? I googled for that, but it seems like there is no solution for my particular constantly changing value of argparser argument. This link [Disable/Remove argument in argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807319/disable-remove-argument-in-argparse) suggests creating parent parser, but I don't understand how it could help my problem.

```
def ytSearchLaunch(video_id):
  argparser.add_argument("--q", help="Search term", default=video_id)
  argparser.add_argument("--max-results", help="Max results", default=25)
  args = argparser.parse_args()
  youtube_search(args)
```

This is whole code.

```
def youtube_search(options):
  youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)
  search_response = youtube.search().list(
    q=options.q,
    type="video",
    part="id,snippet",
    maxResults=options.max_results
  ).execute()

def ytSearchLaunch(video_id):
  argparser.add_argument("--q", help="Search term", default=video_id)
  argparser.add_argument("--max-results", help="Max results", default=25)
  args = argparser.parse_args()
  youtube_search(args)

def checkDateFunction():
    fname = 'file'
    f = open(fname,'r')
    for l in f:
        video_id = l.split()[0]
        ytSearchLaunch(video_id)
```

Comment: I am using it in the example code from youtube api page https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list 
it's importing from oauth2client `from oauth2client.tools import argparser` link for actual code if it's hard to find on youtube api page https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/geolocation_search.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ytSearchLaunch` function is taking an `argparser` object that was created by other code, adding a couple of arguments to it, and then parsing the command line values (which you can also see in `sys.argv`).  It is then passing the resulting `args` namespace object to `youtube_search`.

It would help us if you showed how `argparser` was created, or at least show the `help` or `usage` that it produces.  It would also be nice to see the `args` object after parsing.

If I read this right you want to parse the inputs multiple times, each time with a different `-q` default value. But you can't add the same argument to `argparser` several times.  You can do it once, but on the repeat calls you'll have to modify an existing argument.

Here's a possible fix:

```
def ytSearchLaunch(video_id, added_actions=[]):
  if len(added_actions)==0: # first time
      a1 = argparser.add_argument("--q", help="Search term", default=video_id)
      a2 = argparser.add_argument("--max-results", help="Max results", default=25)
      added_actions.append(a1)
      added_actions.append(a2)
  else:         # repeats
      # change defaults to the -q argument without adding a new one
      added_actions[0].default = video_id
  args = argparser.parse_args()
  youtube_search(args)
```

Comment: That's 100% works. Thank you so much! I just started to scratch my head on how to show the help/usage.

Comment: `-h` is the usual `help` commandline.  But you can also use `argparser.print_help()` or `argparser.print_usage` to show those for debugging purposes.  On occasion I also print `argparser._actions` to see all the Actions have been defined.